# how to display an object certain field in Angular 4/2 selection?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular2-forms, angular4-forms

I have an contact class, which contains a company field(company data type). I have a company class. I have companies, which are company objects. I have a edit component for contacts, where you can edit a contact. It has a mat-select field, which is look like this:

```
<mat-form-field class="matffield">
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="contact.company" name="contactCompany" placeholder="Company" multiple>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let company of companies" [value]="company">{{company.name}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

So you can choose from the companies I have, and you can save it to the contact.company field. It works. But if you save the contact and you want to edit it again the mat-select will not display the companies, which are in the contact.company field. The other input field like this:

```
<mat-form-field class="matffield">
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="contact.full_name" name="contactFullName" placeholder="Teljes név">
</mat-form-field>
```

is display the current contact.surname. So I wan to display the companies' names, which is in the contact.company currently.

It work when I do this:

```
<mat-form-field class="matffield">
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="contact.company" name="contactCompany" placeholder="Company" multiple>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let company of companies" [value]="company.id">{{company.name}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

, but this is not correct, because the contact.company will only contains the id of the companies.

For help, my contact class:

```
import { Company } from './company';

export class Contact{
    id: number;
    company: Company[];
    full_name: string;
    surname: string;
    middle_name: string;
    forename: string;
    nickname: string;
    phone: string;
    email: string;
    primary_communication_chanel: string;
    rank: string;
    greeting: string;
    selected: boolean;
}
```

and my company class:

```
export class Company{
    id: number;
    logo: string;
    name: string;
    phone: string;
    email: string;
    website: string;
    facebook: string;
    country_code: string;
    hq_country: string;
    hq_zipcode: number;
    hq_settlement: string;
    hq_address: string;
    bi_name: string;
    bi_country: string;
    bi_zipcode: number;
    bi_settlement: string;
    bi_address: string;
    taxnumber: number;
    mail_name: string;
    mail_country: string;
    mail_zipcode: number;
    mail_settlement: string;
    mail_address: string;
    industry_id: number;
    employeesnum_id: number;
    yearlyincome_id: number;
    founded: number;
    selected: boolean;
    project: number[];
}
```

**EDITED**

I have a solution. I don't think this is good...
I have a contact-routing module, where I have this route: `{ path: 'people/edit/:id', component:ContactEditComponent }`
So in the ContactEditComponent there is a ngOnInit void.
I modified that:

```
this.route.paramMap
    .switchMap((params: ParamMap) => this.contactsService.getContact(+params.get('id')))
    .subscribe(contact => {this.contact = contact;
      contact.company.forEach(company => this.selectedCompanies.push(company.id))});
```

I also changed the HTML code:

```
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedCompanies" name="contactCompany" placeholder="Cég" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let company of companies" [value]="company.id">{{company.name}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

But now, in the save function i have to write this code:

```
for(let i = 0; i < this.selectedCompanies.length; i++)
{
    this.contact.company[i] = this.companies.find(x => x.id == this.selectedCompanies[i]);
}
```

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is make a selected company like this.

In html:

```
<mat-option (onSelectionChange)="setCompanies(company)" />
```

And in component:

```
private selectedCompanies: any[] = [];

private setCompanies(_company: any){
  this.selectedCompanies.push(_company);
  // lastSelected = this.selectedCompanies[this.selectedCompanies.length -1]
}
```

Comment: This will save only one, the last company i selected to the selectedCompany. And then? How can display the selected companies, when i save it and wan to edit it again?

Comment: Ahh let me change it.

Comment: Ohh, when I select 2 company, this push 10 company to the selectedCompanies array. Why? I do something wrong?
And how to display the selected companies when I come back to edit the contact again?

Comment: Well that is something the mat-options is doing ;) Sorry can't help with that. maybe check for **$event.isUserInput === true**

Comment: The thing is when I select some companies, and save the contact.company is contain the selected companies. So when I edit it again and don't change the companies, the contact.company have the same companies. I want to know when I edit the contact, which companies are already in the contact.company.